# ASP.NET Application Not being accessed by web.config Writing permissions

Tags: c#, asp.net, windows, iis, visual-studio-2019

2 Situations here of permissions and access:

**Cannot Read Configuration File due to Insufficient permissions**
This has happening on every single VM instance of Windows Server V. 2019 standard Build 17763.rs5

- Solution One by many obfuscated answers in this website: change the Application Pool settings in Advance settings, Identity to LocalSystem: Server responds to provide the basic pages, But no layouts, css, no images, Nothing, Pure HTML served at the end and Modules not even signalled (thank you VS Debugger for telling me this 10 times in a row)
- Solution *deux*  Use Windows Security ownership and add the role of the IIS and the other variants that server other roles, NOPE, nothing. also probably security risk.

**Situation 2**
My Workstation had replicated same deployment process from ASP.NET MVC template from visual studio 2019 and application ran fine. Once.
I had a deployed WebApp in my local machine workstation with the Default template for ASP.NET in Framework (not core, I see you there dude), and the IIS module built, worked fine, did it is purpose. and Only worked in my workstation and my final goal is to be it deployable on other machines... UNTIL:

**Cannot add modules to Website Templates made in ASP.NET (Framework)**

After that IIS does not allow me to do anything,some Roslyn something in some answers but that didn't work, but were mostly manual removal of it to make it work, which doesn't fit to make a deployment to many computers at once in few clicks (not my choice).

Did my VS updated something? or IIS? Why my regular setup worked just few days ago and now Nothing, even from scratch cant do it's purpose,

Any Ideas? Questions to my questions?

Comment: Solution one is never a real solution, as using LocalSystem is insane. Solution deux is the right way, but how to set the minimal permissions to application pool identity requires experience on web site/IIS security, and your actual setup. So I won't say it is an easy task to work on. Unfortunately Microsoft designed the whole workflow (develop/deployment) separately so there are big gaps like you observed, but that's not the reason to put all the trouble you met in a single long question and expect reasonable guidance. You have to divide and conquer.

Comment: Solution Deux is that Windows local file system is not even responding to what I do. As admin, safe mode, and IIS_USs dsadksads something, Do not allow it either.

Comment: "Solution Deux is that Windows local file system is not even responding to what I do. As admin, safe mode, and IIS_USs dsadksads something, Do not allow it either." That's the area you might describe with more details and some help from others might come, because that's much more specific for discussion.

Comment: User roles added to the Windows was not a problem before, not means is not a single click and deploy solution.  That one works to an extent but does not work unless I do something more than deploying a server and IIS module. I still wanna ask why did it change all of sudden last 4 weeks?